# Manuscript review decision

Tags: publications

I had submitted a Manuscript in a good journal which has given me the reviews as " Accepted for publication pending revisions"? What does this review actually mean? Is it accepted?

FYI, I have created a response letter in which I have given justification for some concerns and also made the changes that were asked to be made in the figures.

Can anybody please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably means the same as "Minor Revisions" in some other journals: you need to revise your manuscript following the suggestions of the referees, after which the editor will only check that the suggestions were addressed. The reviewers would not need to read the paper again; it can be send for publication as soon as the editor is happy that the revisions were made.

Answer (score 2):

It means exactly what it says:

"Accepted for publication pending revisions".

It's accepted...pending the requested revisions. Essentially, they are going to ask for some changes (usually pretty minor and straightforward) and once those are done to the editor's satisfaction, the paper is accepted.